# Guild Description on SWTOR

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Is the guild description in SWTOR public or private (to guild members only)? I want to put some teamspeak info in game and can't find a good place, this seems like a good place IF its private to guild members only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Researched this a little more and its private (guild only).